# Is Neewer flash gear just rebranded Godox gear? Are they compatible with each other?

Tags: off-camera-flash, compatibility, godox, neewer, rebranding

I've read that Neewer and Godox are the same thing, and that a lot of Chinese flash gear is rebranded. The Neewer Q3 looks like it's the same as an AD200 Pro. I'm curious: is this just the same stuff? If I buy gear from both brands will it all work together? Given the Neewer stuff is often cheaper, it would be nice.

Answer (score 4):

TLDR; **No, they're not the same and they're not compatible.**

### The Neewer Q System is not the Godox X System

You are not the first person to see the physical similarity between Neewer's new "Q" system and Godox's "X" system. The Neewer QPro looks quite a bit like a Godox XPro; a Neewer Z1 has a round head and looks a lot like a Godox V1; and the Neewer Q3 is aping an AD200 Pro. But the UIs are different on the flashes and transmitters, and the Q3's head is fixed, not interchangeable.

There are, in fact, a number of different AD200, uh...homages, such as the Triopo F1-200 & F1-250, Yongnuo YN-200, Visico 2 (aka the Neewer Vision2), and Neewer Q3. All of them have fixed heads; **all** of them are in different incompatible radio triggering systems.

The Neewer Q3 units are **not** made by Godox and are completely incompatible as reported by other folks who purchased them assuming they were the same thing. I suspect they are Meike because the older Neewer QC transmitter (before the Neewer QPro came out as an Godox XPro lookalike) [has a similar case to the Meike GT620](https://imgur.com/a/ewcHk0W), but as they're not identical in UI, that's not proof.

### Generic Rebranding

However, a lot of Chinese flash gear *does* get extensively rebranded, and Neewer *used* to rebrand Godox's 2.4 GHz "X" system gear (e.g., the Neewer NW880 was the Godox TT685; the Neewer NW860 II was the Godox V860 II); but they don't appear to have any Godox gear, aside from the older non-compatible models (e.g., the [Godox TT560](https://web.archive.org/web/20200709155922/http://www.godox.com/EN/Products_Camera_Flash_TT560.html) which has no radio in it is [the Neewer TT560](https://neewer.com/products/on-off-camera-flash-66600004); and also used to be [the Amazon Basics Flash](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01I09WHLW)) under their brand any more.

And Neewer is particularly problematic since they're a generic rebranding, bringing together a host of different gear under one label, assumably to make it easier to sell. Their flash gear has at various times been identified as models made by Godox, Yongnuo, Meike, Triopo, Visico, etc. So, "Neewer" as a brand does not indicate compatibility with anything else that's branded "Neewer".  You have to do more research.

### Rebranding for Support

There is also a different kind of rebranding that is done for a different purpose. Adorama rebrands Godox gear as "Flashpoint R2"; Essential Photos in the UK rebrands it as "Pixapro" and Quadralite as "Stroboss" so that they can easily identify who to extend customer and warranty support to. If it's rebranded, it was clearly purchased from them.

With Jinbei's RT system, which is rebranded as Westcott FJ in the US and Rollei Freeze HS in Europe, an older reputable company is adopting a subset of models from their lineup to expand their own offerings. And they take over the customer/warranty support/repair issues under their rebranding as well.